# How to draw circles around a pentagon using turtle?

Tags: python, shapes, python-turtle

I would like 5 circles, one per side of the pentagon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJBd8.png)

```
import turtle

turtleStar = turtle.Turtle()

for s in range(5):
    turtleStar.forward(100)
    turtleStar.right(144)

turtleStar.left(36)
turtleStar.forward(62)

for p in range(4):
    turtleStar.right(72)
    turtleStar.forward(62)

for c in range(5):

    r = 50
    turtleStar.circle(r)
    turtleStar.right(100)
```

Comment: "5 circles, one per side of the pentagon" I don't understand what that's saying. Do you want a circle for every side with the side of the pentagon being the diameter? Or the vertex being the center of the circle? If possible, can you send a screenshot of what you would want it to look like?

Comment: Can you provide a link, or a simple sketch of what you expect exactly? Or describe in more detail what you mean by "5 circles, one per side of the pentagon"? Are the circles near the points or the middle of the sides? Are they centered on them, or touching? Etc.

Comment: @EricJin On the outside of the pentagon, one circle per side touching two vertices.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBBSa.png like this (bad drawing but you get the idea)?

Comment: @EricJin I posted the link at the top of the post =)

Comment: Are the circles tangent to each other at the same point that they are tangent to the vertex? This probably won't work, but I think the centers of the circles form another pentagon (pointed upside down) with side length 2x of the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use one loop, draw the circles as you traverse the pentagon
- Do some math or work out on paper what you want the turtle to do (e.g. what's the exterior angle of a pentagon?)
- Make sure to read the documentation and make sure the methods you call do what you think they do

This code worked for me:

```py
import turtle
import math

turtleStar = turtle.Turtle()

for s in range(5):
    turtleStar.right(180-54)
    turtleStar.circle(50/math.cos(math.pi*(90-54)/180))
    turtleStar.left(180-54)
    turtleStar.forward(100)
    turtleStar.left(72)
```

Comment: Hey Allie, thanks for contributing that is pretty close but I am trying to get the circles on the outside of the pentagons perimeter

Comment: @grossom, oops! Quite embarrassing, posted prematurely. Please see edited version.

Comment: No worries! I see your on the same path as me haha I just need four more circles now

Comment: @grossom so sorry, I thought the other dude's question with the attached image was your answer, not a question. Having seen the image you linked above I have included the code in my answer that fulfills those tangent requirements. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Allie I got it below as well! I think your code is a bit more readable then mine but I am glad I got it working as this is my first time creating shapes with Python! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyones help! I got was I looking for below!

import turtle

turtleStar = turtle.Turtle()

for s in range(5):

```
turtleStar.forward(100)
turtleStar.right(144)
```

turtleStar.left(36)
turtleStar.forward(62)

for p in range(4):

```
turtleStar.right(72)
turtleStar.forward(62)
```

for c in range(5):

```
turtleStar.right(72)
turtleStar.forward(31)
turtleStar.circle(60)
turtleStar.forward(31)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).